# Toggle Class on cilck based on browser width (resize) via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggleclass

I have a button with toggle class attached to it - and it should work only when the borwser size is below 1200px. It works after refresh but somehow when I resize the window it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't - can't see the pattern. I see on the dev tools the the element is higlighted (so hte script is doing something) but I doesn't toggle the class. Tried to change it to addClass/removeClass but the result is the same. Any advice how to make it work would be much appreciated.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/miunik/pen/oLWOLY

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="level-1">
  <li class="btn">1 level item
    <ul class="level-2">
      <li>2 level item</li>
      <li>2 level item</li>
      <li>2 level item</li>
      <li>2 level item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.level-2 {
  display: none;
}

ul.level-2.open {
  display: block;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setNav() {
    if (window.outerWidth < 1200) {
      $('.btn').on({
        click: function() {
          $(this).children('.level-2').toggleClass('open');
        }
      });
    }
  }
  setNav()
  $(window).resize(function() {
    setNav();
    console.log(window.outerWidth);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is, that you bind a lot of event handlers: every time the window `resize` event occurs, each `<li>` tag (not only the one in level 1) gets a new one. So it depends on the number of event handlers if `toggleClass()` actually toggles or doesn't.

I would only bind one handler, preferably on the document in conjunction with a selector which identifies only the `<li>` tags directly below `.level-1` and ask for the screen size in this handler. You don't even need a `resize` handler for that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".btn", function () {
    if (window.outerWidth < 1200) {
      $(this).children('.level-2').toggleClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

See a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/wu1unvek/

It might be that you want a `resize()` handler anyway to remove the `open` class if the window gets larger:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  if (window.outerWidth >= 1200) {
    $(".level-2").removeClass("open");
  }
});
```

**EDIT**: Adapted to modified question code: Use `.btn` instead of `.level-1 > li`

**EDIT 2**: Added example for `resize()` resetting the `open` class if window gets larger

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Unfortunately, it can't be the solution. I gave the "li" element special class name so the event handler binds only to it and it still reacts the same (unpredictable)  way - sometimes toggle sometimes doesn't.

Comment: Don't know what you mean. I took the code into a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wu1unvek/ and it works like a charm for me. How does it go wrong for you?

Comment: Hi Joachim. Have a look at this screencast I recorded - it explains everything. For me it behaves weird - but it is way beyond my knowledge of jQuery. http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cDieQuiUA1 Seems like $(window).resize()  is a problem here - you were saying there is another way of doing it. Could you give me a hint on how to avoid this behavior I would totally appreciate it. However thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Is it, that you still use `.resize()` to setup an event handler? That would be a problem. I will add an example for my remark about `resize()` in my answer to make it more clear, what I meant.

Comment: Hi Joachim, thank you a lot for help with this. I'll solve this problem as you suggest - work really nice.